# A question on convergence of sets

Tags: real-analysis

Thinking back to some fond memories of real and linear analysis last fall, I recalled  that a sequence of sets $\{A_{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $A_{k} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ for all $k$ converges to a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ if the sequence of characteristic functions of the $A_{k}$ converges to the characteristic function of $A$. Is there something to be said about the relationship between the $A_{k}$ sets and $A$ if the convergence of the characteristic functions is point wise versus uniform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\chi_k$ be the characteristic function of $A_k$ and $\chi$ for $A$.

Suppose the convergence were uniform. Take $\varepsilon = 1/2$, then we should be able to find a $N$ for which $|\chi_n (x) - \chi(x)| < 1/2$ for every $x$ in the domain. In particular, the points of $x$ which are in $A_k$ are exactly the point of $x$ which are in $A$. This holds for all $n \geq N$, in particular eventually we have $A_n = A_{n+1} = \dots = A$.

If the convergence is only pointwise, we just need that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $x \in A_m$ for all $m \geq N$ for some $M$. This is clearly weaker than the previous condition.

As an example, the balls of radius $1-1/n$ centered at zero converges pointwise to the ball of radius $1$, however this convergence is certainly not uniform in this sense.